pip3 install, error : externally-managed-environment
I Code my raspberry pi 4B , Linux 11  Bookworm
sudo pip3 install adafruit-circuitpython-ADXL34x

then

error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
install.
If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
sure you have python3-full installed.

For more information visit http://rptl.io/venv

I have already 'Python 3.11.2'
How can I do?
Check my python version
version is 'Python 3.11.2'

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77634679/7976758 Advice: do not use sudo and do not install Python packages system-wide; use Python virtual environments. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+externally-managed-environment
