Ghostscript module installation issue
I need to use the Ghostscript module in PMython for a project. It's not the first time.
My issue is that on the laptop. I'm using right now (not at home), I can't install the module.
Pip just refuses to proceed, even if it downloads the required files!
console :
pip install ghostscript
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try 'pacman -S
    python-xyz', where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Arch-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using 'python -m venv path/to/venv'.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Arch packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use 'pipx install xyz', which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have python-pipx
    installed via pacman.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

pacman updated ghostscript correctly for my system but won't find the python module
any of the listed solution (pipx, ...) won't work neither
Any idea ??
regards
tried pip, pacman, yay, paru through spyder console, régular terminal
Always the same answer

If you're using a computer that's managed by your IT Department, you should talk to them about installing third-party software.

you can run install with option -v for verbose - to see more details.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77634491/handling-of-python-packages-and-correct-virtual-environment-use , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+externally-managed-environment
