How do I get Pyinstaller on a Chromebook?
I am running Linux. I want to turn a file into an exe, but I do need the pyinstaller to do that. I already installed pip as well. Is another ways to do it?
I tried 'pip install', sudo apt-get pyinstaller' 'python install pyinstaller'.
After I do pip install.


When you say "I tried pip install" did you run just that, or pip install pyinstaller?

I did try to run both

When you run pip show pyinstaller, what do you see? And is there more than one version of Python installed on your machine?

warning: package not found

FWIW, the proper syntax for installing any package with pip is pip install <the name of the package>, not just pip install. Do you get an error when you run  the command pip install pyinstaller?

Also, you may be running into issues because your cwd is named 'pyinstaller'. What is in that dir? Have you tried running the pip install command from outside that folder?

error:externally managed environment

yeah the same shows up for that as well

Hmmm. Does any of the information here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608323/how-do-i-solve-error-externally-managed-environment-every-time-i-use-pip-3

this worked "pip install package_name --break-system-packages

I have version 6.7.0

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Please, show us text, not screenshots of text! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. [Edit] your question, copy/paste from the terminal and properly format it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read. Images are only good to show something non-textual (like colors, fonts, screen positions, etc).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77634491/handling-of-python-packages-and-correct-virtual-environment-use , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+externally-managed-environment

To upgrade existing PyInstaller installation to the latest version, use:
$pip install --upgrade pyinstaller
To install the current development version, use:
$pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tarball/develop
To install directly using pip’s built-in git checkout support, use:
$pip install git+https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller
or to install specific branch (e.g., develop):
$pip install git+https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller@develop

I took a screen shot of the error

I succeeded in doing this by following the steps below.

Install PIP.

sudo apt install python3-pip -y

Update PIP.

python3 -m pip install -U pip --break-system-packages

Install pyinstaller.

python3 -m pip install pyinstaller --break-system-packages

Create an executable from hoge.py using pyinstaller.

$HOME/.local/bin/pyinstaller hoge.py

The executable is created

$HOME/dist/hoge/hoge
